# Access GHS app engine without adding a DNS entry

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a Google app engine application, that works via `ghs.googlehosted.com` (using CNAME with a custom domain).  Is it possible to access that same app by going to `ghs.googlehosted.com` directly, and supply the needed domain in the URL?  Something like  `ghs.googlehosted.com/myapp.example.com/...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the `https://my-project-id.appspot.com/` is that magical address!